# jquery function stops responding after updating gridview with update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

this problem happens after the gridview is updated with the update panel

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="GridGis" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True"   >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="idade" HeaderText="Idade" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cidade" HeaderText="Cidade" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="uf" HeaderText="UF" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="datanasc" HeaderText="Data/Nascimento" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="salario" HeaderText="Salário" /> 
        </Columns>


    </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button4" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>`
```

Comment: When an UpdatePanel refreshes, the html content is completely replaced. Given the small amount of code you've shown, I can only guess that you are binding events or applying plugins to the content in the UpdatePanel, which is all lost when the panel refreshes. You'll need to rebind handlers and reapply plugins after the refresh.

Comment: I'm not using plugins, my jquery function:' $("#GridView1 tr").hover(
       function () {
           $(this).css({ "background-color": "lightgreen" });
           $(this).css({ "cursor": "pointer" });
       },
       function () {
           $(this).css({ "background-color": "white" });
       });'

Comment: You are binding event handlers, however. `.hover()` is shorthand for applying `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers. Rebind the handler after an UpdatePanel refresh, or use event delegation to bind the handler to something outside the UpdatePanel.

Comment: could tell me how to do it? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are losing your event handlers when the UpdatePanel refreshes. My suggestion would be to use event delegation so you don't have to worry about rebinding:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#GridView1 tr', function() {
    $(this).css({ "background-color": "lightgreen", "cursor": "pointer" });

}).on('mouseleave', '#GridView1 tr', function() {
    $(this).css({ "background-color": "white" });

});
```

If you can find an ancestor that is closer to the `GridView` than the `document`, but still outside the `UpdatePanel`, that would be ideal.

Alternatively, something this simple is probably better solved with pure css:

```
#GridView1 tr {
    background-color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#GridView1 tr:hover {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
```